# Как сделать слайдер справа-налево с блоком (слайдом) слева slick slider?

Tags: html, jquery, slick.js

Есть слайдер с двумя слайдами, должно было быть так, что с первого слайда идет прокрутка ко второму слайду справа-налево, как на макете[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получается, что идет прокрутка ко второму слайду справа-налево(благодаря `rtl`), НО мне нужно чтобы второй слайд был слева относительно первого слайда, и "свайп" производился справа-налево ко второму слайду: **[Мой код на codepen](https://codepen.io/nosferatu-id/pen/ZEGmrOo)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
  infinite: false,
  rtl: true
  });
})
```

Конфиг слайдера

Comment: Вроде справа налево идет... Или я что-то не так понял

Comment: @VitaliyAntal да идёт справа налево, но, второй слайд должен быть слева, чтобы с первого слайда, он справа-налево шёл ко второму слайду

Comment: @VitaliyAntal поправил

Comment: Ничего не понял)))

Comment: @VitaliyAntal даже если посмотреть код? Я там вроде понятно все сказал...

Comment: Если второй слайд должен идти справа налево, как он может быть слева? Вы сами себе противоречите)

Comment: @VitaliyAntal не, от первого слайда, должен производится свайп справа-налево ко второму слайду, просто проблема в том что. слайды по умолчанию свайпаются слева направо, и блоки слайдов так и расположены, а мне нужно с первого слайда идти ко второму, но справа-налево

Comment: "проблема в том что. слайды по умолчанию свайпаются слева направо"
 - не заметил этого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обеспечить полноценный эффект "справа-налево" нужно было использовать атрибут `dir` со значением `rtl`, вместе с `rtl: true`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
  infinite: false,
  rtl: true
  })
})
```

```css
.slider {
  background: #333;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: start;
  color: #fff
  width: 500px;
}
.first-slide {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.second-slide {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" dir="rtl" <!-- НУЖНО БЫЛО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ АТРИБУТ dir="rtl" ДЛЯ ПОЛНОЦЕННОГО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ rtl: true -->>
  <div class="first-slide">
    FIRST SLIDE CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="second-slide">
    SECOND SLIDE CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
Второй слайд остается справа, а нужно чтобы он был слева<br />
<i>Я не вставил свой код полностью, но структура такая же</i>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил только width: 500px; и убрал с конфигурации  rtl: true. Не вижу в чем проблема. Вроде работает как нужно.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
  infinite: false,

  })
})
```

```css
.slider {
  background: #333;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: start;
  color: #fff
  width: 500px;
}
.first-slide {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.second-slide {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="first-slide">
    FIRST SLIDE CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="second-slide">
    SECOND SLIDE CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
Второй слайд остается справа, а нужно чтобы он был слева<br />
<i>Я не вставил свой код полностью, но структура такая же</i>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Нет, ваш слайдер работает слева-направо, а мне нудно српава-налево, при этом второй слайд должен находится слева относительно первого слайда, я оставил ответ можете посмотреть